# Single Perceptron - Non-linear Evaluating function

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, neural-network

In the case of a single perceptron - literature states that it cannot be used for seperating non-linear discriminant cases like the XOR function. This is understandable since the VC-dimension of a line (in 2-D) is 3 and so a single 2-D line cannot discriminate outputs like XOR.

However, my question is why should the evaluating function in the single perceptron be a linear-step function? Clearly if we have a non-linear evaluating function like a sigmoid, this perceptron can discriminate between the 1s and 0s of XOR. So, am I missing something here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> if we have a non-linear evaluating function like a sigmoid, this perceptron can discriminate between the 1s and 0s of XOR

That's not true at all. The criteria for discrimination is not the shape of the line (or hyperplane in higher dimensions), but rather whether the function allows **[linear separability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_separability)**.

There is no *single* function that produces a hyperplane capable of separating the points of the XOR function. The curve in the image separates the points, but it is not a function.

[image: You can't separate the blue and red points into separate hyperplanes using a single function]

To separate the points of XOR, you'll have to use *at least* two lines (or any other shaped functions). This will require two separate perceptrons. Then, you could use a third perceptron to separate the intermediate results on the basis of sign.

[image: If you use two lines, you can create two discriminants, and then merge the result]

Comment: *"if we have a non-linear evaluating function like a sigmoid..." "That's not true at all."* Quite so since sigmoid function doesn't make much sense, but I believe I came up with an example of a non-linear evaluating function where a more complicated binary classifier would work; see my answer if interested.

Comment: The function you have suggested will work, but it cannot be handled by a single perceptron. see comment on the other answer.

Answer (score 3):

I assume by sigmoid you don't actually mean a sigmoid, but something with a local maximum. Whereas the normal perceptron binary classifier is of the form:

```
f(x) = (1 if w.x+b>0 else 0)
```

you could have a function:

```
f(x) = (1 if |w.x+b|<0.5 else 0)
```

This certainly would work, but would be fairly artificial, in that you effectively are tailoring your model to your dataset, which is bad.

Whether the normal perceptron algorithm would converge is almost certainly out of the question, though I may be mistaken. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptron#Separability_and_convergence You might need to come up with a whole new way to fit the function, which sort of defeats the purpose.

Or you could just use a [support vector machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine), which is like perceptron, but is able to handle more complicated cases by using the [kernel trick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_trick).

Comment: But by introducing the modulus operator, you are in effect creating _two_ functions, one that compares (w.x+b) with 0.5, the other that compares the same (w.x+b) with -0.5, and then using the signs of the intermediate results in a third classification. This is equivalent to using a multi-layered perceptron.

Comment: Not quite equivalent to using a multi-layered perceptron, as you can't train the weights separately. You'd be adding a constraint between weights in a multi-layered perceptron, and I don't know if this is good.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but i want to leave my thoughts (anyone correct me if i'm wrong).

I think you're mixed the concepts of `linear model` and `loss` or `error` function.
The Perceptron is by definition a linear model, so it defines a line/plane/hyperplane which you can use to separate your classes.

The standard Perceptron algorithm extract the signal of your output, giving -1 or 1:

```
yhat = signal(w * X + w0)
```

This is fine and will eventually converge if your data is `linearly separable`.

To improve this you can use a `sigmoid` to smooth the loss function in the range [-1, 1]:

```
yhat = -1 + 2*sigmoid(w * X + w0)
mean_squared_error = (Y - yhat)^2
```

Then use a numerical optimizer like Gradient Descent to minimize the error over your entire dataset. Here w0, w1, w2, ..., wn are your variables.

Now, if your original data is not `linearly separable`, you can transform it in a way which makes it linearly separable and then apply any linear model. This is true because the model is `linear on the weights`.

This is basically what models like SVM do under the hoods do to classify your non-linear data.

`PS: I'm learning this stuff too, so experts don't be mad at me if i said some crap.`